# Query data from database on sql condition in python

Tags: python, sqlite

just a small problem I have.
What I am trying to do is get both column names and data from a database, using a function which returns two values just like `return columns, data`. The problem that I have is outputting the data. Using the following code

```
for column in build_sql.show_employee_id(registered_employee[0])[1]:
 for detail in [b for b in build_sql.show_employee_id(registered_employee[0])[0].fetchall()]:
  print(column, ":", detail)
```

the print is

```
Name : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
Surname : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
HiredDate : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
PhoneNumber : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
Email : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
Address : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
Position : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
BadgeID : ('Andrei', 'Cioban', '09:28:32 (19.12.2020)', 352395729385723, 'wfoaF@fwaic.com', 'AWiofOAWFLAWiufnLIAWUfnliaIUFAWi', 'Employee', '411372')
```

but I want it to be something like

```
Name: Andrei
Surname: Cioban
# and so on
```

Edit:
This is the sqlite3 code that queries the data:

```
def show_employee_id(ide):
    employee = connection.execute('SELECT Name, Surname, HiredDate, PhoneNumber, Email, Address, Position, BadgeID FROM employees WHERE ID = ?;', (ide,))
    columns = [description[0] for description in employee.description]
    return employee, columns
```

How can I do this? What I've tried doesn't work. I don't understand why it prints a tuple after I looped through the tuple return with the data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall()` gets you a list of the rows in your database.

So the comprehension list will just contain every tuple returned by `fecthall()` (meaning it is useless and you could just have written `for detail in fetchall()`.

As a result, `detail` will take values from a list of tuple, so in each loop iteration, `detail` will be a row of your database.

Maybe you could iterate over the `fetchall()` result with `for row in fetchall` and print what you want using a loop on the columns or a formated string.